# Is there a way to pull the "Display Name" rather than the field name from Rest API for SuiteCRM

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm, suitecrm

So looking to pull in the info from Source_C but only getting back the field value

Lets say my sources in source_c are;

**Field Name**
Email_Mass_Mail
Email_Direct_Email
Meeting_Request
Meeting_Submit

And the Display Name for those sources are;

**Display Name**
Mailchip Email
 
Direct Email 
Email Referral
Website Submission

I am currently only getting Field Name values back but I want to have Display Name as its more friendly for the end users.

Answer (score 0):

You should get (and probably cache) the list of fields for that module.

You can get it from `Api/V8/meta/fields/Accounts` - Accounts is the module name.

You will get a list of all the fields

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "fields",
    "attributes": {
      "id": {
        "type": "id",
        "required": true,
        "dbType": "id"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "name",
        "dbType": "varchar",
        "len": 150,
        "required": true
      },
```

Sadly, there is a pending issue with enum/multienum that is not showing the list on the API call. Its confirmed and set as High priority so I expect to be fixed soon (soon for SuiteCRM is a couple of months) https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/issues/8622

Comment: Great thanks. Is there a way to do this in the 4.1 API?

Comment: The 4.1 will return the label not the value based on the user language so you will be set. Please check the question as valid if it responded your question :)